# Swift MapKit : need to move map to show annotations after using addAnnotations()

Tags: swift, annotations, mapkit, mkmapview, refresh

After adding an annotation array using `addAnnotations()`, I need to move the map (using the mouse) for the annotations to appear! This is very annoying. lol

Does someone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please include the relevant code. Refer to [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for further tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to do UI Changes on the main thread, are you adding the annotations on the main thread?

When you add the annotations, try this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {  

     yourMapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Let me know if you have any more questions or if that resolved your issue